# How to get IP of a domain requested with wget?

Tags: shell, ip, wget

I'm searching for a way to fetch IP address of the domain requested with `wget` command, when the command fails.

I can't use `ping` command for fetching the IP, because the address may change after the `wget` command is terminated.

I would like to perform this in a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `wget` fails, it terminates with non-zero exit status, and the errors are written to the standard error descriptor (2).

So you can check the exit code (`$?` variable), and parse the strings written to the standard error:

```
url='http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1646322'

output=$( wget "$url" 2>&1 )
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  printf '%s' "$output" | \
    perl -ne '/^Connecting to .*\|([^\|]+)\|/ and print $1'
fi
```

*Sample Output*

```
151.101.129.69
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, where wget was the only networking tool available in a container. I needed to get the ip of a domain whether or not wget exited successfully. This is what I ended up doing, in a multi-line shell script:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --no-dns-cache --save-headers https://example.com 2>getip.txt || true
result="$(grep -oE '\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b' getip.txt | head -n 1)"
echo "$result"
```

Broken down,

```
--no-check-certificates
```

to continue even if SSL is not valid

```
--no-dns-cache
```

to make sure we're getting the latest IP

```
--save-headers
```

to print the IP to a file (processing the output of the command does not give the IP in a success case)

```
grep -oE '\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b'
```

To find all IP addresses in the output, and pipe to

```
head -n 1
```

to only return the first, which is what I was looking for.